# RxSwift Driver - issues with nulled UITableView cell frames and background view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

A `UITableView` is fed with data from the `ViewModel` with a `RxSwift Driver`.

The use case is a simple text-based search - when the user types in a string in the `SearchBar`, the API returns results or no results. If no results, the driver returns empty array.

The problem is when there are no results, and then the search query is updated, so now there are results, the cells' frames in the table view are defaulted to (0, 0, 0, 44) - and thus not shown at all. I am setting an initial `backgroundView` to the `UITableView`, which is `nilled` when there are results from the query in the `.do {}` part. The cells are suddenly shown when I scroll down and then back up, but somehow initially they are covered by the background view, which is supposed to be `nil`.

This happens only when transitioning from an empty result to not-empty result. When there are results populated in cells, changing the query string and showing new results works fine.

What could cause the cells' frames to be nulled and how to properly clear the `UITableView` results (and show a No Results message in `UITableView.backgroundView` instead), if the `Driver` emits empty result set?

**ViewModel.swift**

```
var searchText = PublishSubject<String>()

private func getData() -> Driver<[Item]> {
    return self.searchText
        .filter({ (query) -> Bool in
            return query.count > 0
        })
        .asObservable()
        .throttle(0.2, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .flatMapLatest(searchAPI)
        .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])

}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
var viewModel: SearchViewModel!

var tableView: UITableView!
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
var searchBar: UISearchBar { return searchController.searchBar }


override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupUI()
    setupBindings()
}

private func setupUI() {
    tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.frame)
    tableView.register(SearchResultCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SearchResultCell")
    tableView.rowHeight = 56
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag

    tableView.delegate = nil
    tableView.dataSource = nil
    view.addSubview(tableView)

    showMessage(.initial)

    configureSearchController()
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
}


private func showMessage(_ type: SearchMessage) {
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height))
    let emptyMessageLabel = UILabel(frame: rect)

    switch type {

    case .initial:
        emptyMessageLabel.text = "Try searching bla bla"

    case .noResult:
        emptyMessageLabel.text = "No results found.\nTry searching again"
    }

    tableView.backgroundView = emptyMessageLabel;
}


extension SearchViewController {
    private func setupBindings() {
        viewModel.data
           .do(onNext: { [weak self] items in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.tableView.backgroundView = nil
                if items.count == 0 {
                   self.showMessage(.noResult)
                }
            })
            .drive(tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "SearchResultCell", cellType: SearchResultCell.self)) { row, item, cell in
                cell.label.text = item.title
                do {
                    try _ = cell.imageView.kf.rx.setImage(with: item.imageUrl.asURL()).subscribe()
                } catch(let error) {
                    cell.imageView.image = UIImage.init(named: "DefaultImage")
                }
            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

**SearchResultCell.swift**

```
class SearchResultCell: UITableViewCell {

    var nameLabel: UILabel!
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        setupUI()
    }

    private func setupUI() {
        clipsToBounds = true
        autoresizesSubviews = false

        nameLabel = UILabel()
        imageView = UIImageView(image: nil)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)

        nameLabel.textColor = .darkGray
        nameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    }
```

Comment: Where is the close brace for your `switch` statement in the `showMessage(_:)` function?

Comment: The code you show works fine (assuming your `showMessage(_:)` function sets the backgroundView properly.) The bug is probably in your cell construction code, tableView construction code or possibly because you are calling `setupBindings` before the tableView has a width. Show the broken code instead of what you have shown.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the code where the `tableView` and the `tableViewCell` are initialized. The func `setupBindings()` is called after tableView is initialized and it's frame is not zero.

Comment: Sorry, the code you provided doesn't compile or make much sense. What is `snp`? It's not defined anywhere. You cannot override `imageView` inside `SearchResultCell`. Why are you calling `removeSubviews()` on a UILabel? And why does it have one of these `snp`s? Is that from some library you didn't mention?

Comment: Yes, `.snp` is from an AutoLayout DSL library called `SnapKit` - it's now removed as well as the `removeSubviews()`. Why I cannot override `imageView` when the cell inits? I am not using Interface Builder so that should be the way to initialize the views inside the cell, no?